# SP 2013 SSOM Checkin DirectoryNotFoundException

Tags: 2013, check-in, ssom

Trying to recurse through a folder and checkout or checkin all files. But i keep getting a DirectoryNotFoundException on the checkin. Oddly enough, i manually uploaded a file to the Agency folder (the root of our recurse) and that file works perfectly. The other folders / files in the Agency folder were put there by a feature and we just want to make sure all files are checked in.

```
        static void Main(string[] args) {
        string url = "http://site.sp2013.dev";

        using (SPSite site = new SPSite(url)) {
            using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb()) {

                var folder = web.GetFolder("Style Library/Agency");

                RecurseFolder(folder);
            }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    static void RecurseFolder(SPFolder folder) {
        Console.WriteLine("+ {0}", folder.Name);

        foreach(SPFile file in folder.Files) {
            if(file.CheckOutType != SPFile.SPCheckOutType.None) {

                file.CheckIn("asdf");
            } else {
                file.CheckOut();
                file.CheckIn("asdf");
            }

            Console.WriteLine("{0} : {1}", file.Name, file.CheckOutType);
         }

        foreach(SPFolder subFolder in folder.SubFolders) {
            RecurseFolder(subFolder);
        }

    }
```

as soon as i hit file.CheckIn("asdf"); i get

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException' occurred in Microsoft.SharePoint.dll

Additional information: <nativehr>0x80070003</nativehr><nativestack></nativestack>There is no file with URL 'Style Library/Agency/css/ie8-grid-foundation-4.css' in this Web.
```

Is there something special about files deployed via a feature that will keep them from being updated via the SSOM by chance?

Comment: Note: CSOM = Client-Side Object Model, while you're apparently using the Server-Side Object Model.

Comment: oi, fixed it in an edit

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe your module files are *not* deployed as `GhostableInLibrary` (see e.g. [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/186407/35604) for a definition of `GhostableInLibrary` vs `Ghostable`).
Would you share the code your XML element (module) that deploys the files into the library?
`GhostableInLibrary` must be explicitely set on the `Type` attribute of each  `File` node.

EDIT:
The problem was not about the `GhostableInLibrary` type of the file as per OP.
However, OP confirmed the module was deployed as a sandbox solution. When deployed from a sandbox solution, provisioned files are not automatically published (while they are with a farm/full-trust WSP), they stay in checked-out state, and they're checked-out to the user who activated the sandbox.
Beside that, there's something weird with the file C# API, something I already came accros once or twice: `folder.Files` lists all files even those that have no checked-in version (files that are normally visible only by the user who uploaded them), but the `SPFile` object it returns is set to `Exists=false`.

Comment: So i read through your link and i these are all deployed as ghostableinlibrary. here is the xml for that specific file that the exception is being thrown for.     <File Path="Style Library\Agency\css\ie8-grid-foundation-4.css" Url="css/ie8-grid-foundation-4.css" Type="GhostableInLibrary" />

Comment: Is it a sandbox solution or a farm (full-trust) solution?

Comment: Yes! it was a sandboxed solution ... when i changed it and redeployed i was able to get it to use the file.checkin method. Thanks so much for your help. Maybe you should edit your answer to also include a tidbit about sandboxed solutions?