# Which to choose: site pages vs wiki page library

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, wiki-pages, sitepages

We are going to make a site for each deparment, section, etc. We have concluded that "team site" is adequate. Yet, we haven't decided if we are going to use the "Site pages" (only the wiki pages) or the app "wiki page library". I assume that Site pages are a superset of wiki pages.

Is this correct?

Are there any differences?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally , the content Site Page within the **Site Pages library** is a wiki page.

But what is differ from the `wiki page library` and `site Page library` that the `site page library` contains all pages including the home page , and when you add a new page to your site , by default it's created below site page library.

[image]

Regarding a **wiki page library** it's an interconnected set of easily editable web pages, which can contain text, images and web parts.

it's used when you have mostly a need for rich text content; for example, text, tables, links, and images. You can still insert Web Parts or use no Web Parts at all. The HTML content in wiki pages is also subject to versioning if versioning is turned on in the library.

While wiki pages are flexible and very customizable, one of their drawbacks is the lack of metadata that’s automatically available in them. As you add content to the page, the metadata doesn’t automatically follow. That, as it happens, leads us nicely to Publishing pages.

In my opinion, I think the compare between `wiki page` and `web part page` is more useful than comparing with site page that is a wiki page, so I suggest to check also [Difference beween wiki page, application page, web part page and publishing page](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/50232/difference-beween-wiki-page-application-page-web-part-page-and-publishing-page)

Comment: Why shouldn't I use  the wiki pages inside the site pages library?

Comment: Who said this by default all content page inside site page library is wiki page , meanwhile you can create a new wiki page library to create only page from wiki type

Answer (score 2):

We use Site Pages as it allows for more customization. If you want webzones, webparts, javaScript, etc... then this is the way to go.

If all you want is free text with HTML markup then go with Wiki Pages. We use wiki pages for creating things like SOPs or other informational documentation.